# Dynamically change property of Shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I have a shader on a gameObject in Unity, Lets call it FooShader. In FooShader there is a public property called `_fooVal` I want to update in real time.

I've created a blank C# script on the same gameObject.
My first problem is how do I reference this `FooShader` shader? And then once I have a correct reference change its `_fooVal` property?

I've tried using the following to get a reference to the Shader but it doesn't work.

```
gameObject.material._fooVal
```

Comment: Unity contains ShaderUtil to iterate through the shader parameters (see Unity documentation at  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ShaderUtil.html). By knowing the parameters, you can then set them by using SetFloat, SetColor etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you cannot access the variables in a shader directly, you have to use the methods on the material object. Try the following code to get your renderer component and set the value of (for instance) a float in its shader:

```
Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
rend.material.SetFloat("_fooVal", 2.0f /* Your value here */);
```

Here is the [Unity3D reference on materials](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html) - there are also `SetInt`, `SetColor`, `SetVector`, and other methods depending on what type of variable you are trying to update.

Comment: Why SetFloat have yo be inside Update() and not only once on Start()?

Comment: @MatanMarciano Only because the asker wants to update the value in real time. If you only want to set it once, you can put it in Start().