# How to Access unity shader Properties in script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to access two properties `_Color` and `_Color2` and want to change the values using script as we can see the value is in the format `(1,1,1,1)` so how can I change it its basically color values.

```
Shader "Custom/SpriteGradient" 
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("LeftColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Color2("RightColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Scale("Scale", Float) = 1

        _StencilComp("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255
        _ColorMask("Color Mask", Float) = 15
        // see for example
        // http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/980924/ui-mask-with-shader.html
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change property of Shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000049/dynamically-change-property-of-shader)

Answer (score 2):

See [`Material.SetColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html)

Modified example from the API

```c#
void Start()
{
    //Get the Renderer component from this object
    var renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    var material = renderer.material;

    //Call SetColor using the shader property name "_Color" and "_Color2" and setting their color to red
    material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
    material.SetColor("_Color2", new Color(1, 0, 0, 1));  
}
```

The name means the actual property name, not the display name. You also can get the actual property names e.g. by selecting a shader asset and check the inspector